# Spark dataframe reads hive struct type as array instead of map

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a basic question to ask regarding how spark dataframe reads in hive `struct` types. For example, I have a hive table that looks like the following:

```
user_id (string)
current_address (struct<city:string,state:string>)
previous_address (array<struct<city:string,state:string>>)



+--------------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| user_id      | current_address              |  previous_address                                               |
+--------------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1            |{"city":"Tampa","state":"FL"} | [{"city":"Newark","state":"NJ"},{"city":"Denver","state":"CO"}] |
+--------------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2            |{"city":"NY","state":"NY"}    | [{"city":"Austin","state":"TX"}]                                |
+--------------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

SparkSQL reads this into a dataframe as:

```
root
 |-- user_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- current_address: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- state: string (nullable = true)
 |-- previous_address: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- state: string (nullable = true)

+--------------+-----------------+--------------------------+
| user_id      | current_address |  previous_address        |
+--------------+-----------------+------------ +------------+
| 1            |[Tampa,FL]       |[[Newark,NJ],[Denver,CO]] |
+--------------+-----------------+--------------------------+
| 2            |[NY,NY]          | [[Austin,TX]]            |
+--------------+-----------------+--------------------------+
```

which looks like hive `struct` types is read in as an array.The plan later is to convert dataframe to map and do some other things using the key and its value

How to make spark read these structs fields i.e. `current_address`, `previous_address` as key value like `Map` rather than array and array of arrays so that I'd end with something like `Map[String, String]` and `WrappedArray[Map[String, String]]` instead of `Array[String]` and `WrappedArray[Array[String]]`?

Comment: You have `array<struct<city:string,state:string>>` in Hive and that's exactly how Spark loads it. There is no map on either side. So where exactly is the problem here? Are you concerned about the visual representation? Or do you actually want tot [convert things to map](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#map_from_entries)?

Comment: Thanks, I would definitely like to convert to map

Comment: you want a key value structure when you only have a tuple everytime ?